# bokeh tooltip : can it display another bokeh graph?

Tags: python, bokeh

I can't find information on this topic : I have a bokeh graph, and I have a tooltip on it. I would like the tooltip to display data on a graph form.

Here an example : I ahve a map with a tooltip. If I get the historical value of the population, I would like to display it as a little graph /sparkline on the tooltip. Meaning the html/javascript of the tooltip should take the list of values and make a graph out of it (or ask a bokeh server for the graph ? But I didn't dig the bokeh server yet).

Would that be possible ?

[image]

Comment: I was just talking about this possibility yesterday. I think it might be feasible already, or if not, only require a little more work to make it so. If you'd like to collaborate on an example like this (and making a PR to add docs or an example) that would be fantastic. I'd suggesy coming by the public mailing list https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh since SO is not very good for back-and-forth, iterative collaboration.